# How to find the child class a function argument is instance of in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have three classes: Animal, Cat and Dog. Cat and Dog both extend Animal. I have an array of Animal objects. These objects can be either Cat or Dog.

Initially, I had two functions, one for each Animal child class. But, since they essentially did the same thing, minus a couple lines of code, I was thinking of combining the two functions and passing an Animal array as an argument, that would essentially be either a Cat array or a Dog array. To implement the few different code lines that each class will have to do, I need to get the class of each individual object in the array, but the code I wrote can't figure out that the object is either of the Cat class or the Dog class.

The code I've tried is below. I also tried making animals of type any, to no avail.

```js
export class Animal{}

export class Cat extends Animal{}

export class Dog extends Animal{}

export class Service {

    public insert(animals: Animal[], callback: Function) {
        animals.forEach((c: Animal) => {
            if (c instanceof Cat) {
                var thisCat: Cat = <Cat>c;
                //...
            } else if (c instanceof Dog) {
                var thisDog: Dog = <Dog>c;
                //...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can this be done with only one function or do I have to keep my two seperate "service" functions for each Animal child class?

Comment: Mark the method abstract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine in [Typescript since 1.4](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-guards), and is even easier than you have it: You don't need to cast `<Cat>c` or `<Dog>c` because `instanceof` works as a type guard.

That said, you may choose to make an abstract function (as Li357 suggested in the comments) to better organize your code, depending on whether you want the Animal or the Service to bear the responsibility of accommodating new Animals or new behaviors for existing Animals.

[Live link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Animal%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Cat%20extends%20Animal%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20meow()%20%7B%2F*%20...%20*%2F%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bark()%20%7B%2F*%20...%20*%2F%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Service%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20insert(animals%3A%20Animal%5B%5D%2C%20callback%3A%20Function)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20animals.forEach((c%3A%20Animal)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(c%20instanceof%20Cat)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Inserted%20a%20cat%3A%20%25s%22%2C%20c)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.meow()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20if%20(c%20instanceof%20Dog)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Inserted%20a%20dog%3A%20%25s%22%2C%20c)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c.bark()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20s%20%3D%20new%20Service()%3B%0D%0Alet%20animalArray%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20Cat()%2C%20new%20Dog()%2C%20new%20Cat()%5D%3B%0D%0As.insert(animalArray%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%3B)

```js
class Animal{}

class Cat extends Animal{
    meow() {/* ... */}
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    bark() {/* ... */}
}

class Service {

    public insert(animals: Animal[], callback: Function) {
        animals.forEach((c: Animal) => {
            if (c instanceof Cat) {
                console.log("Inserted a cat: %s", c)
                c.meow();
            } else if (c instanceof Dog) {
                console.log("Inserted a dog: %s", c)
                c.bark();
            }
        });
    }
}

let s = new Service();
let animalArray = [new Cat(), new Dog(), new Cat()];
s.insert(animalArray, () => {});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, it was correct. I just didn't initialize the objects correctly, that's why they weren't recognized as instances of Cat/Dog. Thank you for the polite and detailed reply!!